# R xml2: copy a document

Tags: r, xml2

Reading the [XML manipulation vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xml2/vignettes/modification.html) from `xml2`, and a [side by side comparison](https://gist.github.com/nuest/3ed3b0057713eb4f4d75d11bb62f2d66) to the `XML` package, it seems to me `xml2` doesn't have a function to copy and XML document or nodeset. I think `XML` got the `xmlClone` function, though I haven't used it. It means, `xml2` requires a workaround. So far I found out this:

```
library(xml2)

x <- read_xml("<foo>
  <bar>text <baz id = 'a' /></bar>
  <bar>2</bar>
  <baz id = 'b' />
</foo>")

x_copy <- xml_unserialize(xml_serialize(x, NULL))
```

I am wondering if really this is the most straightforward solution, or I am missing something? Also, isn't this too inefficient for large documents?